# OpenCV: How to detect differences between two different images of the same object

Tags: opencv, comparison, difference

I just started to work with OpenCV.
My goal is to compare two different images of the same object, each with different lighting conditions, different background and from a slightly different angle, and to detect if the object changed between the two images.

Lets say I make pictures of a front door every few days and i want to detect if there are any new small stains or scratches on the door.
I started by detecting the door in the images with traincascade, but now I don't know how to continue. 
By googling I only found techniques like Feature matching, Template matching and Comparing histograms, but I don't think they work in my case. Is it possible with OpenCV to detect tiny differences when the pictures are not identical and how can I achieve it?

Comment: Repeat Question:
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343258/how-to-identify-changes-in-two-images-of-same-object)

Comment: you want to detect whether there are differences between 2 images but some kind of differences should be ignored. You'll have to specify which kind of differences should be ignored and perform some kind of "normalization". After that you can compare pixel values. But this task seems much too complex to me, especially if you're new to image processing. Afaik, in practice it's normally (industry) done by assuring that the conditions are mostly the same when creating the images.

Answer (score 0):

Stains or scratches are usually borders, try to take a roi of the door and sobel your image in case you use an static point of view por the camera (it's much easier that way) in the other hand, with multiple points of view, try to identify your door, with four corners, doing a perspective transform and so on...